# How to link an android application with a website to retrieve infromation

Tags: php, android

I am creating a shopping cart app and i am willing to update the products database through a website. what i want is whenever i will update the database through the website and then log in to the shopping cart app, i want all of the products to be visible in the app. Now i can create the website to update the database from there but how can i link the website with the app? I am a beginner and i have just started learning android application development. So someone please help me to find the way to do so.I will be thankful if someone provide me with necessary guidelines and any examples which i can look up on to follow and develop my shopping cart app accordingly.

Comment: A good place to start is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).

Comment: @user3393926 I think you have been working with PHP or Dot Net before taking upto Android Dev so I guess, you must know Ksoap and Rest Webservices. This is what you need:- A "webservice" uploaded at a domain which the Android App can hit and fetch data from your database. I hope this should be sufficient for you, if you have any queries feel free to post back

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an API layer which your app can use. The app can make API calls to the server which will return all the information you need from the database and then display in the app.

So whenever you update your database from the website and then login from the app, the app will make API call to fetch latest data and then display.

Comment: Thanks Sameer S, for the information. can you please tell my how to create a custom API layer. Any tutorial will very helpful for me.